# how to call parts of dataframe when making glm models in R

Tags: r

[image: My data is shown on image 1, along with other covariates.]

My data is stored as a data frame called `data` and what I am trying to do is build generalized linear models in R to model the number of total views.

this code isn't working:

```
model1= glm(data$Total.Views~data$Sport, data$dum.SB, family=poisson)
```

How do I call out parts of data frame in my model?

Comment: The syntax would be something like `model1 = glm(Total.Views ~ Sport + dum.SB, family=poisson, data=data)` if you want to predict Total.Views from Sport and dum.SB.

Comment: +1 If you want to fit a glm on only part of the data do `model1 = glm(Total.Views ~ Sport, family=poisson, data=data[data$dumb.SB == XYZ,  ])` where `XYZ` is the part of the data you want to fit. But if these comments don't help, paste in some of your data from R to the question...